# i want to add dropdown with checkbox

Tags: jquery, node.js

Currently I have a multiple dropdown but i want to add dropdown with checkbox
my code is look like this

```
<select class="form-control dropdown-check-list" style="margin-left: 1px; margin-top: 9px;" id="ddl_parameter"   multiple="multiple" name="tablecol"  required/>
```

for options i am using ajax call to get data from db and i want dropdown woth checkbox for this options

```
GetParamter();
         function GetParamter() {

             $.ajax({

                 url: "/GetParamter",
                 type: 'get',
                 datatype: 'JSON',
                 success: function (response) {
                     var data = JSON.stringify(response);
                     var data = JSON.parse(data);

                     $("#ddl_parameter").empty();
                     $("#ddl_parameter").append('<option value="0">Choose an Option..</option>');
                     for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                         $("#ddl_parameter").append('<option value="' + data[i]["name"] + '">' + data[i]["name"] + '</option>');

                     }

                 },

                 error: function (jqXHR, exception) {
                     //alert(xhr.responseText);
                 }
             });
         }
```

Comment: have you tried appending a checkbox input on your element `option`?
Something like this:
`$("#ddl_parameter").append('<option value="' + data[i]["name"] + '"><input type="check">' + data[i]["name"] + '</option>');`

Comment: I guess your `response` is already `JSON`. You don’t need to `stringify` it.

Comment: $("#ddl_parameter").append('<option value="' + data[i]["name"] + '"><input type="check">' + data[i]["name"] + '</option>');
This query doesn't work I have already tried this

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boostrap Multiselect](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect) for dropdown with checkbox,

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/css/bootstrap-multiselect.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="http://cdn.rawgit.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect/master/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<select id="ddl_parameter" multiple="Multiple">

</select>


    $(function() {

  var data = [{
    name: 'test'
  }, {
    name: 'test2'
  }]

  for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    $("#ddl_parameter").append('<option value="' + data[i]["name"] + '">' + data[i]["name"] + '</option>');
  }

  $('#ddl_parameter').multiselect({
    includeSelectAllOption: true
  });

});
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/9c4jsqf9/132/

Comment: After adding this bootstrap i was able to select only one option but i want to select minimum of two options thats why i choose checkcoxes

Comment: @prabhu I have updated the script, We can select more than one using boostrap multiselect. Please check the demo as well.

Comment: Thanks a lot issue was resloved